# Calculation of $1^x + 2^x + \cdots + n^x$ where $x$ is a even number

Tags: integers

If $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 = 1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^2$, then is there a formula to calculate $1^x + 2^x + \cdots + n^x$ where $x$ is a even number?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula That wikipedia page also inludes the proof.

Comment: Faulhaber's formula is for *positive* even numbers. For also negative even numbers consider Euler summation formula, for the partial sums of $\zeta(x)$.

Comment: If $x$ is the even number 0 then the answer is $n$.